# Where to buy tefillin parts

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin, safrus

Does anyone know where to get tefillin parts, specifically retzuot and batim as a friend of mine needs new batim and I need new retzuot.

Comment: Does anyone know R' Melech Michaels (mezuzadepot.com)?

Comment: I only know him via his reputation and blog. I would say he's a great source to buy from because he has a reputation for good work and he is very strict about hagaha

Comment: That's what I've heard, furthermore one of the local rabbanim from the Boston area is from Monsey and also has heard good reports about him.

Comment: Of course the caveat is that the best man to buy from is not always the best man to have check your STA"M because of "Hatorah chasa al memonam shel yisrael". Are you dead set on buying online?

Comment: I'm not looking for parshiyot, otherwise I would not look online, I am looking for retzuot for me and battim for a friend. On the battim, my friend is looking for a sh"r with a sephardi ש (vellish), while his present sh"r has a Chaba"d ש.

Comment: @Yitzchak, I recently got new tefillin through R' Michaels and I am quite satisfied. His sofer wrote them according to Minhag Ashkenaz (Beit Yosef with צ similar to the Ari) He sent me the computer check sheet which showed that the sofer acquitted himself admirably.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to order online, you could try [Oter Yisrael](http://www.otr-israel.com/)  - even though they don't seem to have those items for sale, they are very friendly and may ship you individual items. (Personal recommendation; I've bought many pairs of Tefilin from them over the past 30 years for my brothers and sons.)

Another place which has an online presence with a very good reputation is [Tefilin Bet El](http://www.tefillin.co.il/english/repair/index.html), though I've never actually been there. They seem to sell Tefillin straps online.

If you are in Geula there's a great place just off Kikar Shabbat at the top of Yechezkel where I replaced my Tefillin straps recently.

Or you could go to [HaSofer](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=retzuot) - or visit them virtually. They sell straps online.

The only ones selling Batim online seem to be [GooDaica](http://www.goodaica.com/product_info.php?cPath=3_22&products_id=177&osCsid=hpbkqr76o861oob55lpg9dief6) - but I know nothing about them.

Comment: "If you are in Geula…" does it have a website?

Comment: No - it does not. But I added haSofer, in Geula - and its URL to the answer. http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=retzuot

Answer (score 0):

http://www.judaism.com/giftware/tefillin.asp?nt=Bm indicates that they sell tefillin entire, but e-mail them: they will sell tefillin parts also.
The address is info@judaism.com.